# Nested Draggable Elements in Snap.svg - Exclude Element as Drag Handle

Tags: javascript, svg, draggable, snap.svg

Using Snap.svg, I'd like to enable some elements within a draggable Group to be separately draggable as well - but when these child draggable elements are dragged, the parent group should NOT be dragged as a whole.  In other words, I need to exclude some child elements of a group from being a drag handle for the group.

In the example below, a Group is set up with a draggable Rectangle element and a Circle element.  The Rectangle is the draggable child element, and the Circle is the non-draggable child element.  The parent group itself is draggable thus making the circle a handle to drag the entire group.  I want to make it so the draggable rectangle cannot be used to drag the entire group, but while remaining a member of the group so that it is included when the circle is used to drag the group.

You can see the odd behavior of both the rectangle being dragged and the group being dragged when you use the rectangle to move everything.

**How can I excluded the rectangle from being used to drag its parent group while allowing it to be dragged separately?**

jsfiddle Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/EDT9J/

HTML Code:

```
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
```

Javascript/ Snap.svg Code:

```
var s = Snap("#svg");

var draggableChildBlock = s.rect(150, 150, 100, 100, 20, 20);
draggableChildBlock.attr({
    fill: "rgb(236, 240, 241)",
    stroke: "#1f2c39",
    strokeWidth: 3
});

var circleDragHandleForParentGroup = s.circle(280,280,20);

var draggableParentGroup = s.g(circleDragHandleForParentGroup,draggableChildBlock);

draggableChildBlock.drag();
draggableParentGroup.drag();
```

Comment: This isn't odd behaviour I don't think, if you have attached a handler to the group and the element. You either add a drag handler to the group, or to the individual elements that need handlers. You can always make a custom handler and check some attribute of the element and decide to drag or not depending on that.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Ian; I'll try writing custom handlers as suggested and post a solution if I come up with something.  Agreed that this behaviour isn't a bug (or odd), just different than what I want.  The behaviour I'm looking for is to not fire/handle the dragging on a group if one of its children is being dragged - to ONLY do the inner local drag handling.   Seems like a custom handler is required as suggested.  Will update with an answer once I have something.